# UWP: Collection of a collection

Tags: c#, json, observablecollection, uwp

I have a json collection (Collection of PhotoAlbums) & each Album holds a json collection (Collection of images).

I display all the Images in a (Albumb)Collection using:

```
            var imageCollection = await App.DataModel.GetImageCollection();
```

It reads a json file & loads the images. This is invoked when you open any album.

My problem is since the GetImageColleciton looks for the same json file on all albums, they share the same ImageCollection.

I need to find a way disconnect them. I'm thinking that finding a way to save different json filles for each album will be best.

Any best practices to accomplish this?

When the app opens, it creates both an album collection & image collection:

```
public DataSource()
    {
        _imageCollection = new ObservableCollection<ImageCollection>();
        _albumCollection= new ObservableCollection<AlbumCollection>();
    }
```

Maybe I could only instantiate a collection of albums & not the image collection. Then find a way to assign each image collection to the album they were created in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a collection of images, each image having an Id. Then, a collection of albums. An album is a collection of image Ids.

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public Uri Url { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> ImageIds {get; set; }
}

public DataSource()
{
    _imageCollection = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
    _albumCollection= new ObservableCollection<Album>();
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea. So far, my images all have a GUID that I can use to associate them an album that also have a GUID. I'm trying to wrap my head around the logic so in the flow, an album is created. then within the album you add the image. As you add the image it adds the image to the collection of all the images in all the albums. The image GUID is added to that particular AlbumGUID Collection. When Viewing the images in the album. Foreach GUID in AlbumGUIDcollection add image to AlbumImageCollection. Then display AlbumImageCollection. I'll give it a try!! :D